# how can we do c means clustering in r,showing overlapping clusters

Tags: r

This is what i have tried

```
setwd("C:\\Ds")
reddit <- mtcars
reddit <- na.omit(reddit)
View(reddit)
cars<-reddit[,c(9,23)]
na.omit(cars)
col1<-cars[,1]/1000000
col2<-cars[,2]/1000000
z<-cbind(col1,col2)

cl<-means(z,4)

options(scipen = 10)

format(z,scientific=FALSE)
plot(z, col = cl$cluster,color=TRUE,las=1,xlab = "Gross in millions",ylab = "Budget in millions")
points(cl$centers, col = 1:2, pch = 18, cex = 2.5)
```

I want to create something like this:

[image]